# Print sum of numbers 1 to 200 except mults of 4 or 7 in Python

Tags: python

I had a question about using the modulus operator in Python and whether I have used it in a understandable way.

This is how I've written the script:

```
#sum numbers 1 to 200 except mults of 4 or 7
def main():
    sum = 0
    for x in range(200+1):
        if (x % 4 and x % 7): #is this bad???
            sum = sum + x
    print sum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So my questions are:

- Should I spell out the modulo more clearly? ie `if x % 4 != 0 and x % 7 != 0`
- Should I be approaching this in a very different way?

Comment: Omitting the `!= 0` is fine, even preferable. Most everyone understands that non-zero numbers are `True` in  most high-level languages, so you're not exploiting some tough-to-remember quirk that will trip you up later.

Comment: @David: "In most high-level languages"? I'd assume that the number of high-level languages in which this is not true is greater than the number of low-level languages in which it is not true.

Comment: @sepp2k I'm not sure I understand your comment. Could you explain further?

Comment: @Kyle: You make it sound as if `0` being false (and the other numbers being true) was a concept introduced by high-level languages (otherwise why say "most high-level languages" instead of "most languages"). This is not true - 0 being false was a concept introduced by machine language. And as a matter of fact I believe there are more high-level languages in which 0 is not usable in place of `false` than there are low-level languages in which 0 can not be used as false.

Comment: @ sepp2k, I got it now. I had originally submitted this code for a quick online test to qualify for an interview. And after I clicked submit I thought, "geez, that's probably a crappy way to make code someone else could read." I really wanted a feel for how more experienced programmers would look at it. Especially using the modulo in the way I did, that a remainder = `True`.

Comment: @sepp2k - I wasn't denying the case for low-level languages, only speaking about most high-level languages that I know. As for machine language, in 65c02 (the one I know) you have BEQ and BNE which test for equality and inequality to zero, thus zero was neither `true` nor `false` by definition.

Comment: I find `sum += x` more compact and elegant than `sum = sum + x`

Comment: @ Ori, I got confused there, forgetting that python has the `+=` operator, but not the `++` increment operator.

Comment: I just want to add that I also think the `!= 0` should be explicitly written out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your use of `%` is fine, but that could be simplified to:

```
def main():
    print sum([i for i in range(201) if i % 4 and i % 7])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Edit:* Since I had a bug in there, that's a pretty clear indication that the `%` is a tripwire. Instead, I'd probably do:

```
def divisible(numerator, denominator):
    return numerator % denominator == 0

def main():
    print sum(i for i in range(201) if not(divisible(i, 4) or divisible(i, 7)))
```

Comment: Ahhh... seeing it in a generator expression makes me feel like I should make the comparison explicit, as a relative n00b, it confuses me what the comparison is doing exactly. I think that's bad since it's my code.

Comment: What elegant looking code.

Comment: @munificent - The `or` should be `and` to skip numbers that are multiples of 4 and/or 7. I thought Kyle had it wrong at first, but after careful consideration I'm 93.84% sure it should be `and`.

Comment: Thanks Munificent! I think you answer helped me a lot in understanding generator expressions too.

Comment: @David - You're right. This is actually one of the things I don't like about how this uses `%`. `i % 4` means "*not* divisible by four" which is backwards from what you expect (but also what we want, which makes it hard to read.

Comment: @munificent, this was really the essence of the question. I was really trying to figure out if my usage of the modulo operator was abusive, and I think it was. Because it looks like it should do one thing, but instead it does the other. Thanks for editing to the correct code.

Comment: @Kyle: This is not a generator expression, it's a list comprehension. You can tell because it's surrounded by square brackets. However it *should* be a generator expression as there is no benefit to generating a list here. So you should remove the brackets.

Comment: Updated to be clearer, I think.

Answer (score 4):

This is a more generalised version of the answers already given:

```
def sum_excluding_multiples(top, factors):
    return sum(i for i in range(top + 1) if all(i % factor for factor in factors))

print sum_excluding_multiples(200, (4, 7))
print sum_excluding_multiples(200, (3, 5, 10, 9))
```

This is @Sjoerd's answer as Python code:

```
def sum_excluding_multiples2(top, factor1, factor2):
    def sum_of_multiples(m=1):
        return m * int(top / m) * (int(top / m) + 1) / 2
    return (sum_of_multiples() - sum_of_multiples(factor1) 
        - sum_of_multiples(factor2) + sum_of_multiples(factor1 * factor2))

print sum_excluding_multiples2(200, 4, 7)
```

This is more complicated and harder to read, and I'm not sure how to generalise it to exclude multiples of more than two numbers. But it would be faster if very large numbers were involved, since it solves the problem mathematically instead of by iterating through a range.

Answer (score 3):

My program is the shortest possible:

```
print 12942
```

Use the formula of inclusion/exclusion.

There should be `200-(200/4)-(200/7)+(200/28) (Using integer division) = 200-50-28+7 = 129` terms in the sum.

The sum must be `s(200) - 4*s(200/4) - 7*s(200/7) + 28*s(200/28) where s(n) = sum from 1 till n = n*(n+1)/2`.

This evaluates to `0.5* (200*201 - 4*50*51 - 7*28*29 + 28*7*8) = 0.5*(40200 - 10200 - 5684 + 1568) = **12942**`.

Why write a program if you can use math?

(I'll admit I used a calculator to multiply and add the numbers)

Comment: Because just doing the maths doesn't teach you anything about the programming language you're using.

Comment: @dreamlax I think that "your piece of code is more complex than required. Use a bit of math to simplify it" is a valid comment during code review. This is not learning-a-language.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's also not codegolf.stackexchange.com. We're reviewing the algorithm, not the result.

Comment: I don't find this solution very helpful, but in code as an algorithm it would be.

Comment: @KyleWpppd I don't know enough Python to turn this into correct Python code, that's why my answer has just one print statement. If anyone writes some Python code for the s() function, the integer divisions, and calling the s function, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: I think `print(12942)` would be better, since it would run on both Python 2 and Python 3. :-P

Answer (score 2):

I think `x % 4 != 0` is clearer than `x % 4`, because:

- The standard way to check if a number **is** divisible is `x % 4 == 0`.  Of course that could also be written as `not x % 4`, but usually, it's not.  `x % 4 != 0` is more in line with the standard way of writing tests for divisibility.
- `x % 4` is probably more error-prone.  [Quoting munificient](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/794/print-sum-of-numbers-1-to-200-except-mults-of-4-or-7-in-python#comment1474_795):

  > 'i % 4 means "not divisible by four" which is backwards from what you expect (but also what we want, which makes it hard to read.

It's not really a big deal though.

---

A few more comments on your code:

Don't shadow the built-in function `sum()` with your variable `sum`.  Instead, use `total` or something similar.

You don't need the parentheses in `if (x % 4 and x % 7):`.

As has been mentioned in the comments, write `sum = sum + x` more concisely as `sum += x`.

I would make `main()` return the number and then write `print main()` in the last line.  This way, you could reuse the function in a different context.